# only refresh region of page with iron router + meteor (is it possible?)

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I recently started creating a app with meteor, and i run into an issue where i am stuck.

What i want to achieve is to have a app with 2 yield regions.
1 yield region is a left sidebar, the other region the main content of the side.

I am using Iron-Router to create routes.

There should be routes where both regions should refresh / update. This is no problem and i got this working.

What i fail to achieve is that on some routes, it should only rerender /refresh 1 of the regions, not both.

After trying with different routing settings, i am not really sure if what i want is possible at all.

TL;DR:

Is it possible to have 2 yield regions in layout, but to have a route where only 1 of this regions gets refreshed ?

Comment: Iron router should be smart enough not to rerender a region that does not have its data context or template changed. Could you post your code? A better choice would be - if you are not too far down the road - switch over to Flow Router.

Comment: hi. thanks for suggestions. i am not to far into building the app structure, so i will have a look at flow-router now. I have not looked at flow-router, so it might be the answer to my question. If i have to stick to iron-router for some reason, i will update my question with some code.

Comment: Oh then definitely go with flow router. That's the defacto option now.

Comment: have been playing with flow-router the last hours, and it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

iron:router already provides what you need. You just need to name the other yield regions inside templates like this:

```
//template that loads to the main {{>yield}}
<template name="someTemplate">
    {{> yield 'second-yield'}}
</template>

Router.route('/pathYouDesire', function () {
    this.render('anotherTemplate', {
        to:'second-yield',
        data: function () {
            //your data
        }
    })
},{
    name: 'singlePost'
});
```